# How to deploy spring boot application using couchbase on GCP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nosql, google-kubernetes-engine, couchbase

I have created a spring boot app, and using couchbase buckets as database, I want to deploy my docker image of application on Google kubernetes engine. But I don't know how to deploy the buckets on Google cloud. Please help

Comment: These couchbase tutorials [1](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/current/tutorial-gke.htm) [2](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/current/install-kubernetes.html) [3](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/current/howto-couchbase-create.html) might help. Otherwise I suggest improving the question stating the programming problem or making sure you are using the correct platform (e.g serverfault) per the following guides [4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you using EE? if so, you can use the Autonomous operator to create everything for you